# Error capybara js: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Im having problems when i try to config my capybara test to respond js. This is my test:

```
test "creating_expense", js: true do
        visit expenses_path
        click_link('New Expense')

end
```

The error is:
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb:11:in `test': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 0):

The default minitest `test` method doesn't support metadata on tests (the examples you're copying were probably using RSpec).  To swap to the JS driver you need to change the `current_driver` in a setup blog as shown in the Capybara README - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitest

If you want to add support for metadata on tests you can look at the minutest-minidata gem - https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-metadata#example-with-capybara